# How to implement the navigation in a multiple cell uitableview using swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am now implementing a tableview with 3 different cells that should be lead to 3different pages. should I implement the code in prepareforsegue or didselectrowatIndexPath?
I have already created 3 different viewController which should be linked by each of the cell and also set up the segue identifier in storyboard.
Could anyone be kind enough to including some example code and important code description?

Thank you advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would also choose the prepareForSegue function, but I used indexPath for the selected row instead of the identifier.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TargetViewController1
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TargetViewController2
    } else {
        var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TargetViewController3
    }
}
```

It works in my application :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I usually use Storyboards to create my applications flow, I setup different segues to each target viewcontroller.

Then in `didSelectCell` I call `performSegue` and the corresponding identifier.

In `prepare(for:)`, I check for the segue identifier if necessary (for example to set the current view controller as the delegate of the destination.

If you go fully programmatically, there is no need for segues and you could just show/present the new view controller in `didSelectCell`